# How to turn variable name into string in JS?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am trying to write a convenience wrapper for console.log, and I would like to print any variables passed in along with their contents.

Can I turn a variable name into a string in js?

Comment: You mean, pass variables to a function as parameters and get the names of these variables? If so, it's not possible. It doesn't even make sense to write something like: myvariable.name. I don't get it

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want something like this:

```
function Log(data)
{
    console.log(input variable name, data);
}
```

Then I don't think it is possible:

For convenience.. you could do something like

```
console.log({ "your variable name": your variable});
```

Which turns the input to an object that does contain the variable name you want to log.
A little more typing, but perhaps makes the console output more readable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility. And here is how

```
var passed_variable = '65'; // The actual variable
var varname = 'passed_variable'; // The name of the variable in another variable
```

Now, pass the `varname` around but **not the actual variable**. When you need to the value of the variable you can simply do :

```
console.log(varname, ' : ', window[varname]); // Outputs, passed_variable : 65
```

*I hope you find a way not to use this. :)*

Comment: unless `passed_variable` resides in the global space, it won't be visible as `window[varname]`. And I don't want to have to put my variables in the global scope in order to log them.

Comment: and, of course, prefixing something with `var` is something you do when you _don't_ want it to end up in the global scope - in which case the log explicitly won't work (unless the code itself is in global scope, in which case the `var` keyword is merely pointless)

Comment: @JanDvorak, Yeah the implication is it being in a global scope.

Comment: which `var` does the exact opposite of. Even if this is fixed, though, it's still a bad way to do your average-day logging.

Comment: @JanDvorak No `var` used inside a function or scope limiter does that.

Comment: if you want something to be explicitly global, why not use `window.passed_variable = ...` rather than saying `var` and praying the snippet does end up in the global scope? What do you mean by "scope limiter"?

Comment: @JanDvorak, Fine then use `window.passed_variable`, I prefer initializing variables with `var`. You do not need to make big fuss about this. By scope limiter, I meant anything that limits one's scope to outside. Some examples being functions, others anonymous callback functions, objects  etc...

Comment: rhetorical question: why do you prefer `var` over `window.`? And the answer is: because `window.` makes stuff global while `var` restricts the variable to the local scope. Anyways, exporting stuff to the global scope just to be able to be lazy about logging is a bad idea.

Comment: @JanDvorak, Where was the topic of Logging Jan, Why are drifting off shore here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38257/discussion-between-jan-dvorak-and-starx)