# get variable name into string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, variables

```
var abc = '123'

var def = '456'
```

need to write `somefuntion()` which convert variable name into string

like

```
alert ("value of" +somefuntion(abc) +"is"+ abc +"and value of" +somefuntion(def)+" is"+def );
```

should be like this

```
alert ("value of abc is 123 and value of def is 456")
```

i have searched and tried few solution 
and idk how this link can help cuz i know you will say its duplicate but i tried it and it didnt work

[How to turn variable name into string in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074583/how-to-turn-variable-name-into-string-in-js)

Comment: String literals?

Comment: Use objects. I dont think you can do that with literal variables. Try `var data = { abc: '123', 'def': '456'}; var s = ''; for (var k in data) { s += 'value of ' + k + ' is ' + data[k];}`

Comment: It's impossible with plain variables. You could use anything else depending on your use case.

Comment: I found the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript) to be very useful.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the code below.

```js
const abc = '123';
const def = '456';

const varToString = varObj => Object.keys(varObj)[0]

alert ("value of " +varToString({def}) +" is "+ def +" and value of " +varToString({abc})+" is "+abc );
```

What this basicly does is, you pass the variable to `varToString` as an object using `{variable}`. `varToString` then returns an `array` with the passed variable as *value*.

```
[
  "abc"
]
```

We grab this *value* using the `[0]` selector (Object.keys(varObj)**[0]**). Now it returns

```
abc
```

Comment: Thanks @Red , yes it strange requirement :)

Comment: It is a strange requirement, for me too. Thanks for the question and thanks for the answer

Comment: what if i want to obtain the name of an object property ? is there any possible way to do so ?

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş Yes, just use `object.keyName`.  BTW `varToString()` accepts an `object` as parameter, so `varToString(object)` will return all `keys` in that *object*.

Comment: well, i was lookin how to get the name of a function, then i learned the javascript function actually has a property `.name` which returns the string representation of the methods name (in most of the cases) . i needed this to pass an instance and the name of the function which belongs to the passed instance of an object.

Comment: If you provide me with an example at https://jsfiddle.net I can look at what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it:

```
function getVariableName(v) {
    for (var key in window) {
        if (window[key] === v)
            return key;
    }
}
var abc = '123';
var def = '456'
alert ("value of " + getVariableName(abc) +" is "+ abc +" and value of " + getVariableName(def) + " is " + def);
```

Comment: 1. You iterate over ALL properties in window = REALLY BAD. 2. `let` and your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A neat way of doing this would be:

make an object as :

```
const data = {
    abc: {
        key: 'abc',
        value: '123',
    },
    def: {
        key: 'def',
        value: '456',
    }
}
```

and then when you want to access them, you can do :

```
alert ("value of" +data.abc.key +"is"+ data.abc.value  +"and value of" +data.def.key+" is"+data.def.value );
```

or

```
const abc = {key: 'abc', value: '123'};
const def = {key: 'def', value: '456'};

alert ("value of" +abc.key +"is"+ abc.value  +"and value of" +def.key+" is"+def.value );
```

Comment: yes i know that we can do it that way , but our requirement is to not change it from variable