# How to print the variable name it self in javascript console

Tags: javascript

```
function printVariableName(name){
   console.log()//Here variable name should be printed...    
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need to have the string representation of the name of an instance variable...?

Comment: Duplicate of [Variable name as a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I think this is the answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468361/get-variable-name-into-string-in-javascript/47468674